# Checkbox labels wrapping

Tags: css

I can't seem to figure out how to stop the labels from wrapping here.  Any thoughts?

```
                <div>
                <h4>Risk Category</h4>
                <ul class="checkbox-grid">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkStrategic" value="Strategic" /><label>Strategic</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkEnvironmental" value="Environmental" /><label>Environmental</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkMarket" value="Market" /><label>Market</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkCredit" value="Credit" /><label>Credit</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkOperational" value="Operational" /><label>Operational</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkCompliance" value="Compliance" /><label>Compliance</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkBenefit" value="Benefit" /><label>Benefit</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkValue" value="Value" /><label>Value Delivery</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkProject" value="Project" /><label>Project Delivery</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkService" value="Service" /><label>Service Delivery</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkSecurity" value="Security" /><label>Security</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

[Code Pen Showing the Problem](http://codepen.io/jd80104/pen/rOwwLY)

Thank you in advance.
JD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the display to inline instead of block. Block level elements tend to expand to their 100% width of the parent. `inline` or `inline-block` elements will align with their sibling elements.

```
#dialog-form label, input {
  display: inline;
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/mewwON)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the following rules:

```
#dialog-form .checkbox-grid input,
#dialog-form .checkbox-grid label
{
  display:inline;
}
```

The reason is that a previous rule set `display:block` to all `label` and `input`.

These new rules reset behaviour only for this kind of elements *children* of `.checkbox-grid`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I appreciate it.